# How to manage code in multitab application?

Tags: c#, .net, version-control, tabs, controls

I'm making application in .NET C#.
It is not my choice but it has to be "multi-tab" application.
I have one window with tab control with many tabs.
There are many controls on every tab. Now all my event handlers and stuff is in main window file.

How to manage this program.
Is there any way to keep content of every tab in separate file (maybe class)?

Comment: Presuming that you have fixed and determined look and funtionality of each tab, you could subclass TabPage for each tab that you have.

Answer (score 2):

Can use a frame and reference a page or user control

```
   <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Tab1 Page">
            <Frame Source="TabPage.xaml" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab2 User Control">
            <Frame Source="UserControl1Tab.xaml" />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

A User Control is probably cleaner but I use Page out of habit.
They both have code behind for event handlers.
If you need to pass data then can do it in the ctor (but then you cannot assign the Source in XAML).